# How to interface raspberry 2 Model B to SIM900 GPRS/GSM Shield

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, sim900

I bought the SIM900 GPRS/GSM Shield to send SMS and I would like link it to Raspberry 2 Model B.

https://www.amazon.it/dp/B01M9J4N56/ref=asc_df_B01M9J4N5652721737/?tag=googshopit-21&creative=23402&creativeASIN=B01M9J4N56&linkCode=df0&hvdev=c&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=

[image]

What is the best way hardware to interface both ? 
via UART ?

Could you provide the hardware link and the way for testing ?

Software side I would like to use python 3 language to interface both.

Can you provide the code example ?

Thanks